# Sandboxing Mongo->execute(MongoCode) in PHP to prevent any DB interaction

Tags: php, mongodb, serverside-javascript

As a feature in the software I'm writing, I'm allowing myself to create calculators written in JS to compute the fees to be applied to a specific set of data, using said data as a reference. Since I'm using Mongo, I can run this safely server-side, and the browser can just call a php page and get the response. The function will be written from an administration control panel and saved to the database. I of course won't be doing any db interactions from inside that function, but executing mongocode is done within the database, so mongocode by nature can do `db.foo`

Just to protect myself and anyone else who might end up writing calculators, I've set `db = null;` in `$context` being passed to `new MongoCode()`

It looks a bit like this:

```
$sample = [
    'estimatedvalue' => 200,
    'estimatedcost' => 400,
    'contractor'    => false,
    'db'    => null,
];
$fees = [
    '_id'   => new MongoId(),
    'name'  => 'Friendly name!',
    'code'  => new MongoCode('function(){return (contractor ? estimatedCost : estimatedValue)*0.01; /* If a contractor is doing the work, base fee on cost. */}', $sample),
];

$a = $this->siteDB->execute($fees['code']);

if(isset($a['errno'])){
    echo $a['errmsg'];
}else{
    var_dump($a['retval']);
}
```

Fortunately, that works, and if I was to inject that into all context, there would be no `db.` commands runnable. I don't want to create a point where NoSQL injection can happen!

An example of something that this prevents is:

```
 'code' => new MongoCode('function(){db.foo.remove();}', $sample),
 // Since db is now null, the above won't work
```

My concern: Are there any other variables that exist in this MongoCode Execute environment that could be potentially harmful to leave in a user-editable function? I couldn't find any documentation on what else is accessible through mongocode functions. If `db` is it, then I'm all set!

Comment: MongoCode is basically evaled JS code on MongoDBs end, it is not server-side however it is real code that runs in a real envo as such and variables that are editable could cause a problem if manipulated to have code in them. Your database might be relatively safe but your server might not and remember JS is single threaded too so even though some one might not be able to get to your data (might) they can still have some fun

Comment: By server not being safe, you're speaking of things like loops causing hanging or something, right? I suppose that's an inherent risk of eval() anywhere. It sounds like you have a deeper understanding of this than me. What types of exploits could take advantage of eval'd code on a single threaded process?

Comment: Indeed if some one can't get at your data they will just have fun killing your server. A single thread will lock all other processes from running on that thread, so the JS engine being single threaded means that no other JS can run as well, the JS can also take write lock if need be. So the type of exploits are, as you say, loops and general misbehaviour. I have never witnessed the effects of these exploits personally because I prefer to just avoid them but not using the JS engine built into MongoDB except for MR...if I must.

Answer (score 1):

This is not safe, and I don't think you can have a user-editable JS function that is.  For example, this requires no variables and shuts down your server:

```
> db.eval("(new Mongo('localhost:27017')).getDB('admin').shutdownServer()")
```

They can insert data, drop databases, connect to other servers in your system, and generally wreck havoc.

If you are trying to allow a user-editable compute function in JavaScript, use a separate JS engine, pull the values from MongoDB, and pass the values + user-defined function to the totally separate JS engine.

Comment: Although I never PLAN for it to be user-editable, things like this are why I was uneasy about it enough to ask. If one was to find their way in they already are going to be able to do damage, but this specific part could be the worst. Your answer is very helpful - thanks. I actually wasn't really aware that there were other PHP js engines, but after research, it seems like replacing this with V8 JS would be my safest option for longevity. For now I may set both db and Mongo to null, thus preventing new and current connection access.. for sure v8js is near the top of the todo's though

Comment: Using a dedicated js engine will probably not only be safer, but faster, too.  Good luck!